# Angular. Make an Observable collection passed in @Input binding

Tags: angular, observable

Here is code example:

**films.component.ts**

```
  @Component(...)
  class FilmsComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() films: Film[];

      public addButtonShow$: Observable<bool>;

      public ngOnInit(): void {
          this.addButtonShow$ = of(this.films)
              .pipe(
                  map(films => !!films.length)
              )
      }  
  }
```

**films.component.html**

```
    <film *ngFor="//iterating by filmsCollection"></film>
    <button *ngIf="addButtonShow$ | async">Add new film</button>
```

I would like to show button only if films collection is not empty, but when **OnChanges** hook triggered addButtonShow$ is not.

How can I Observe my films collection change and change "Add button" visibility. (**Without using ngOnChanges and change showAddButton flag**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to create  `Observable` you can use your collection directly like

```
<button *ngIf="films?.length">Add new film</button>
```

Comment: Good idea. thanks! Also of() completes observable collection, so addButtonShow$ doesnt trigger when films collection updates

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to inject the films service in the films component and either subscribe to films changes or get the films from the service inside it.